# Python - process ended with exit code 3221225477

Tags: python-3.x, xlwings

I've searched on this forum for a possible workaround, and tried my best, but none is working. below is the issue. I've a function which process websocket data and dump into an excel

I tried to use a wrapper/loop around the function, but still its failing.

I am utilizing, xlwings to copy data to the excel as below

```
def websocket_data_process():
          xw.Book(xcelfile).sheets[shets1].range('A40').options(index=False).value = futDf
```

----where futDf is pandas datafrme

The issue is whenever, I am editing the excel at 'A40' Range manually (while the funcion is running), I am getting error like process ended with exit 3221225477. (I googled and came to its a access denied issue). Is there any way that I can workaround this crash and again resume the function, once editing is down..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the response, but I resolved it,
The issue happens because the xlwings trying to access the existing excel which is either locked or not available to access it.

solution: I've created an instance of Excel with xlwings context manager and provided full permissions to the account which is running the excel and it's been resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want. You can ask for a pause. The solution below will only work with windows.

```
import os
os.system("pause")
```

or this will work with any system.

```
input('Press <ENTER> to continue')
```

Of course you need an statement such as

```
for i in range(50):
    rng = f'A{i+1}'
    if rng == 'A40':
        input('Press <ENTER> to continue')
    # Do your things here ...
```